# How do you set the value off a button back to False when not pressed in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x , y, height, width, color):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y
        self. Height = height
        self.Width = width
        self.Color = color
        self.Pressed = False
    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.Color, (self.X, self.Y, self.Width, self.Height))
    def draw_text(self, text, surface):
        Text = font.render(text,1, black)
        surface.blit(Text, (self.X + self.Width//4, self.Y + self.Height//4 ))
    def mouse_event(self, surface, color):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        #mous[0] is the x coordinate of the mouse and mouse[1] is the y coordinate
        if self.X + self.Width > mouse[0] > self.X and self.Height + self.Y > mouse[1] > self.Y:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, (self.X, self.Y, self.Width, self.Height))
            if click[0] == 1:
                self.Pressed = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do an else statement in your co

```
if click[0] == 1:
            self.Pressed = True
else:
            self.Pressed = False
```

So if not clicked, it will set to False.

Comment: Also, if I helped, upvote and accept as answer. This indicates to the community that you found success in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
self.Pressed = (clik[0] == 1)
```

or

```
self.Pressed = bool(click[0])
```

but as I remeber `click` has boolean values so you need only

```
self.Pressed = click[0]
```

---

BTW: to make code more readable we use `CamelCase` names only for classes. For variables, functions, methods we use `lower_case` names. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

Use `pygame.Rect()` to keep button size and position

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
```

and then you can check mouse with

```
if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse):
     self.hover = True
     self.pressed = bool(click[0])
```

`mouse_event()` should only checke event and `draw()` should draw it - and you can use `self.rect` to draw it

```
if hover:
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect)
    surface.blit(self.text, self.text_rect)
else:
```

You can use it to center text on button

```
text_rect = text.get_rect()
text_rect.center = self.rect.center     
surface.blit(text, text_rect)
```